# An effective way of finding the order of the zero $z=0$ of $e^{\sin z}-e^{\tan z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

An effective way of finding the order of the zero $z=0$ of $f(z)=e^{\sin z}-e^{\tan z}$?

What I tried is developing both exponentials by their Taylor series around $z=\sin z$ and $z=\cos z$, getting eventually $$f(z)=\sin z [(1+\frac{\sin^2}{2!}+..)-(\frac {1}{\cos z}+\frac {\sin z}{\cos^2 z}+...)]$$

By developing again $\sin z$ I can extract $z$, but I still have a function which is $0$ at $z=0$. The order should be 3.

Any hints on how to continue will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\exp{(\sin{z})} &= \exp{\left (z-\frac{z^3}{6}+\cdots \right )}\\ &= 1+z-\frac16 z^3+\cdots +\frac12 \left ( z-\frac16 z^3+\cdots \right )^2 +\frac16 \left ( z-\frac16 z^3+\cdots \right )^3+\cdots \\ &=1+z+\frac12 z^2+O(z^4)\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}\exp{(\tan{z})} &= \exp{\left (z+\frac{z^3}{3}+\cdots \right )}\\ &= 1+z+\frac13 z^3+\cdots +\frac12 \left ( z+\frac13 z^3+\cdots \right )^2 +\frac16 \left ( z+\frac13 z^3+\cdots \right )^3+\cdots \\ &=1+z+\frac12 z^2+\frac12 z^3+O(z^4)\end{align}$$

Then

$$\exp{(\sin{z})}-\exp{(\tan{z})} = -\frac12 z^3 + O(z^4) $$

so the order of the zero at $z=0$ is $3$.

Comment: What happened to the $\frac{1}{6}z^3$ from the third-order term of $\exp(\sin z)$?  Oh, neat - cancels a term from the first-order term. Nevermind.